# Filter spark RDD with PySpark by column name and its numerical value

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am translating Scala / Spark model into Python / Spark. The problem is I have RDD with about 1 million observations and about 33 columns. 
I am splitting the RDD based on numerical threshold ('Time'). The time variable is in numerical format (double) (not posix).

Here is Scala source code:

```
// get the time to split the data.
val splitTime = data.stat.approxQuantile("Time", Array(0.7), 0.001).head

val trainingData = data.filter(s"Time<$splitTime").cache()
val validData = data.filter(s"Time>=$splitTime").cache()
```

and here is my PySpark failed interpretation:

```
splitTime = data.approxQuantile("Time", [0.7], 0.001)
trainingData = data.filter(data["Time"] < splitTime)
validData = data.filter(data["Time"] >= splitTime)
```

The first line works fine. The problem starts when I try to use the threshold on the RDD. I also couldn't decode the Scala format `s" >=$ "` around the condition and its importance in the condition. Internet source on the meaning of `s" >=$ "` are vague.

Answer (score 1):

`approxQuantile` returns either `List[float]` (single column case like here) or `List[List[float]]` (multi columns case) so you have to extract the values:

```
splitTime = data.approxQuantile("Time", [0.7], 0.001)
data.filter(data["Time"] < splitTime[0])
```

or

```
(litTime, ) = data.approxQuantile("a", [0.7], 0.001)
trainingData = data.filter(data["Time"] < splitTime)
```